# LogMeIn or GoToMyPC Scan Using NMap or Similar Utility

Tags: remote-access, nmap, logmein, gotomypc

Is there a way to scan my entire subnet for LogMeIn, GoToMyPC or any similar applications?

I was considering using NMap or Zenmap or a similar portscanner but I'm not quite sure which ports these applications rely on.

Comment: What do you mean? nmap can scan any port of a given address.

Comment: I suspect that certain computers on my network still have LogMeIn free installed and it would be nice to ferret them out without logging into each one individually.